# QGIS: vector layer: changing polygon overlay in an nested polygon

Tags: qgis

I have a polygonal layer. The source of the layer is contained in a shapefile.
When I reduce the opacity of the layer, I realize that a polygon "la seine" overlays the polygon "seine et oise"
How to nest them?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can display the smallest feature above the larger ones.

Expand the `Layer Rendering` section, check the box near `Control feature rendering`, click the "sort" icon to the right and instruct to sort by `$area descending`.

It will compute the area of each feature and draw the biggest ones first (bottom), then the smaller ones (top)

[image]

Comment: ok for you answer about symbology. What about areas count ? Does the overlay of the small polygon distort the calculation of the area of the large polygon?

Comment: It shouldn't. Each feature is independent from each other